# How to run the procedure

Tags: oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NG_ZAPIN_FTRREPORT
(
  WI_NAME IN VARCHAR2
)
AS 
  OUT_RESULT VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  OUT_RESULT:= 'SELECT * FROM NG_ZAPIN_FTRCHECKLIST WHERE WI_NAME := ''||WI_NAME||''';
END;
```

This is a sample procedure written by me.
Help me how to run this procedure with passing paramter and getting the query output

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC NG_ZAPIN_FTRREPORT('wi_name');
```

where wi_name is the value of WI_NAME that you want, although I'm pretty sure that your procedure isn't going to work in the way that you expect (but that is a different question).